# Integration - change of integrands within the integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I came across this equation in a paper:

$$\int_\pi^{p_*}\left(\int_p^{p_*}h(u)\;\mathrm du\right)S'(p)\;\mathrm dp=\int_\pi^{p_*}[S(u)-S(\pi)]h(u)\;\mathrm du, 0\leq\pi\leq p_*$$

I am not sure if this is correct, as this is not the usual change of integration order for a double integral. Can someone please explain why this makes sense?

Comment: I think regular Fubini's theorem is for expressions like :
$\int_a^{b}(\int_c^{d}h(x,y)dy)dx$      
where c and d are functions of x. The above equation is confusing me since this is effectively:     
$\int_a^{b}(\int_c^{d}h(x,y)dy)g(x)dx$

How can I reconcile the two?

Comment: Sorry, the comment was dumb. Here the inner integral is simply $H(p_*)-H(p)$, where $H$ is an antiderivative of $h$. You may simply integrate by parts. When integrating $S'(p)$, introduce the antiderivative $S(p)-S(\pi)$ instead of the usual $S(p)$.

Comment: Thanks, this helps- integration by parts was the "trick" I was missing. I am new here, so not sure how to formally "accept" your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is the usual change of order of integration. Draw a picture. When you change the order, you note that $\pi\le u\le p^*$ and, for fixed $u$, we have $\pi\le p\le u$. Then they apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: When you want to change order of integration in a double or triple integral, it helps to draw the region of integration. From the original integral you have $\pi\le p\le p^*$, and for each fixed $p$, we have $p\le u\le p^*$. Draw this region in the $pu$-plane. (Hint: The lines $p=\pi$, $p=p^*4, $u=p^*$, and $p=u$ should show up.)

Answer (score 0):

At first this also appeared to me as a case of fubini's theorem. When that didn't make sense, I tried substituting inner integral with H(p*)- H(p) but wasn't able to solve until Jean-Claude Arbaut commented above suggesting using integration by parts. Using integration by parts and treating each part separately leads to straightforward result.

$\int_\pi^{p_*}\left(\int_p^{p_*}h(u)\;\mathrm du\right)S'(p)\;\mathrm dp $
$\\=\int_\pi^{p_*}[H(p*)-H(p)]S'(p)\;\mathrm dp$   $\\=\int_\pi^{p_*}H(p*)S'(p)\;\mathrm dp - \int_\pi^{p_*}H(p)S'(p)\;\mathrm dp $         $\\ =H(p*)*(S(p)-S(\pi))\;\mathrm  - \int_\pi^{p_*}H(p)S'(p)\;\mathrm dp $
$\\=H(p*)*(S(p)-S(\pi))\;\mathrm  - \int_\pi^{p_*}d(H(p)S(p))\;\mathrm  - \int_\pi^{p_*}h(p)S(p)\;\mathrm dp $
$=H(p*)*(S(p)-S(\pi))\;\mathrm  - [H(p*)S(p*)- H(\pi)S(\pi)]\mathrm  - \int_\pi^{p_*}h(p)S(p)\;\mathrm dp $
$=S(\pi)*(H(p*)-H(\pi))\;\mathrm  - \int_\pi^{p_*}h(p)S(p)\;\mathrm dp $
  =RHS